# "Driver does not support this optional feature" while trying to run quartz jobs with Amazon Redshift

Tags: java, spring, amazon-redshift, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to run quartz scheduler with Amazon Redshift as the data source. I am getting `Driver does not support this optional feature` error while storing quartz job.

[image: Error message]

My quartz datasource configuration is as shown below:

`org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL=jdbc:redshift://redshift.abcd:5439/abc?autoReconnect=true
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user=user
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password=password`

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if you removed autoReconnect=true - does that help? see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-options.html

Comment: @JonScott This does not work

Comment: hi, wondering if you have found a solution. I'm having the same issue when trying to write pyspark dataframe to redshift, oddly only partial data loaded, and it failed with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Redshift does not support some key SQL commands found in other servers. The main one that troubles me most is the lack of support for the SEQUENCE. Further, the AUTO INCREMENT is not supported instead there is an IDENTITY type which has two parameters of SEED and STEP. Also, IDENTITY may not be issued in sequential order.

Another problem is that many of the recent jdbc42, jdbc41 drivers ARE NOT THREAD SAFE. Their call to perform a prepared statement is very problematic. It took me a month to figure it out and finally settle on version 1.2.10.1009 of either jdbc41 or jdbc41 drivers for compliance.

Bottom line, it simply may not work when you do not control the database functionality of the application (meaning having no source to make changes).

I'm sure it was not what you wanted to hear.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to change the driver because some drivers have compatibility issues either with version or data types.

You can try this driver with name : redshift-jdbc42-2.1.0.16

[Link to download](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazon/redshift/redshift-jdbc42/2.1.0.16/)